# Is it possible to change the appearance of one panel in a facet_wrap()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I want to change the appearance of the panel on the right so that the border colours are the same, without affecting the one on the right. Is that possible, and if so, could someone please show me how?

```
April_2020_StayHome_CPI + 
  facet_wrap(monthlyDateL ~ ., labeller = as_labeller(month_names)) + 
  ggtitle("The effect of lockdown in April 2020 on CPI in Europe") + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = "CPI (2010 = 100)", col = "Stay Home Orders") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect("lightblue"), 
        plot.background = element_rect("cornsilk")) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "darkred") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = colours) + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "red")) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", colour = "black"), 
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black")) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16, family = "Comic Sans MS"))
colours <- c("no" <- "white", "yes" <- "black")
```

[image: my visualisation]